# Repetitive sed use on same file

Tags: linux, shell

Below is the shell script I am using to replace 200 plus strings in nagios.cfg.

I want sed to replace all 200 strings in same file but instead its copying the content 200 times with each having one change.

```
    #set -x
    cat partthree | while read  LINE
    do hostnam=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo $hostnam
    a=`less hosts | grep $hostnam -A5 | grep -i md5sum | awk '{print $2}'`
    b=`less partthree  | grep $hostnam | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo $a
    echo $b
    sed  "s/$a/$b/g" hosts >> sample
#   sed  "s/$a/$b/g" hosts > sample will change only last occurence
    done
```

Tried using sed -i "s/$a/$b/g" hosts directly

@Expected output:

```
define host {
        address        sampleaddress
        alias           samplealaias
        host_name       samplealhostname
        _md5sum         def(with replaced string)

}
```

Output

```
define host {
   address         sampleaddress
   alias           samplealaias
   host_name       samplealaias
   c8h(origanal string)         def(string that is supposed to replace original c8h value)

}
```

Comment: That's because `>>` is "append" each time `sed` runs, it will append `hosts` to `sample` - what I mean is, its doing what you told it to do. You need to take the changed file and then loop on it on each iteration.

Comment: Not that `sed -i "s/$a/$b/g"` will certainly fail if `$a` and/or `$b` contain regex characters (`(`, `[`, `.`, `*`, ...) or sed's separation character (`/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do the job. It starts with the initial `hosts` file and performs the individual replacements one after another. The main difference to the original script is that the replacement results are not appended to the result file, but are applied in-place (`sed -i`) on the result file.

```
# start with 'sample' = 'hosts'
cp hosts sample

# perform replacements one after another in 'sample'
cat partthree | while read LINE ; do
    hostnam=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}'`
    a=`less hosts | grep $hostnam -A5 | grep -i md5sum | awk '{print $2}'`
    b=`less partthree  | grep $hostnam | awk '{print $2}'`
    # modify 'sample' in-place
    sed -i "s/$a/$b/g" sample
done
```

Comment: Could you post some example *input* and the expected *output*, especially the contents of `hosts` and  `partthree`?